# CSS transition shorthand with multiple properties?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, shorthand

I can't seem to find the correct syntax for the CSS transition **shorthand** with multiple properties. This doesn't do anything:

```css
.element {
  -webkit-transition: height .5s, opacity .5s .5s;
     -moz-transition: height .5s, opacity .5s .5s;
      -ms-transition: height .5s, opacity .5s .5s;
          transition: height .5s, opacity .5s .5s;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: 0;
}
.element.show {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I add the show class with javascript. The element becomes higher and visible, it just doesn't transition. Testing in latest Chrome, FF and Safari.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I'm looking for the shorthand version to scale my CSS down. It's bloated enough with all the vendor prefixes. Also expanded the example code.

Comment: Check this documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions

Comment: Do you actually change the values of height and opacity? Otherwise they do not change

Comment: I'm not too well-versed with CSS transitions - are the double `.5s` values after `opacity` intended?

Comment: The documentation does not give an example for using the shorthand version with multiple properties. Height changes from 0 to 200px, opacity from 0 to 1. The second .5s is a delay on the opacity transition. I want an element to grow in height, and when that is finished, fade it in.

Comment: Ah yes, the delay value.

Answer (score 918, accepted):

Syntax:

```
transition: <property> || <duration> || <timing-function> || <delay> [, ...];
```

Note that the duration must come before the delay, if the latter is specified.

Individual transitions combined in shorthand declarations:

```
-webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
-moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
-o-transition: height 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
transition: height 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
```

Or just transition them all:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
```

Here is [a straightforward example](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/qAxnK/18/). Here is another one [with the delay property](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/qAxnK/19/).

---

**Edit:** previously listed here were the compatibilities and known issues regarding `transition`. Removed for readability.

Bottom-line: just use it. The nature of this property is non-breaking for all applications and compatibility is now well above 94% globally.

If you still want to be sure, refer to http://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't work for me. I also can't use the all property as I have a delay on the second property.

Comment: It works in Chrome 17, Firefox 10, Safari 5. No means to try IE right now :(. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/qAxnK/

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle to work with delays: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/qAxnK/1/

Comment: It seems to work, I'll look into my project and see if I can get it working. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any performance/memory/other implications to using `all` instead of listing the specific properties? E.g., if I'm planning to transition `background` and `color` only - am I better off specifying both, or just using `all`? Also - given that IE6-9 doesn't support transitions, and IE10 supports them unprefixed - is there any upside/downside to including the `ms-transition:` directives?

Comment: There is definitely a performance impact when transitioning all properties instead of simply the one you need. It might cause serious damage if you have a lot of elements transitioning *all* properties at the same time. About `ms-transition`, I don't know of any reason, now that IE10 is out, why anyone would still use `ms-transition` instead of the standard `transition`. It won't cause any trouble to have both, but it will, especially on a transition-heavy stylesheet, bloat your CSS. More importantly, the file size will also take a hit.

Comment: I had the same issue and it appeared that using "transition: opacity 1s .5s, max-height .5s 0" wasn't not working while "transition: opacity 1s .5s, max-height .5s 0s" was. First time I see an unit required for a zero value in css!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that using 'all' is slower than specifying specific properties.

Answer (score 571):

If you have several specific properties that you want to transition in the same way (because you also have some properties you specifically *don't* want to transition, say `opacity`), another option is to do something like this (prefixes omitted for brevity):

```
.myclass {
    transition: all 200ms ease;
    transition-property: box-shadow, height, width, background, font-size;
}
```

The second declaration overrides the `all` in the shorthand declaration above it and makes for (occasionally) more concise code.

```css
/* prefixes omitted for brevity */
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    box-shadow: red 0 0 5px 1px;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    /*note: not transitioning width */
    transition-property: height, background, box-shadow;
}

.box:hover {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  box-shadow: blue 0 0 10px 3px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover box for demo</p>
<div class="box"></div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/sTP4v/)

Comment: This is useful! Not just because of the `transition-property` override, but also because for example `transition-delay` needs to be specified after the shorthand (at least in webkit). In other words the shorthand implies a `transition-delay` of 0 and putting a standalone delay before the shorthand sets it back to 0.

Comment: @duncanwilcox you can do `transition: [props] [duration] [easing] [delay] ` in every modern browser

Comment: Prefer this answer MUCH more than the accepted answer.

Comment: @duncanwilcox, can you clarify what you mentioned. If I added a `delay` before the shorthand, does that not get applied? that doesn't seem to be the case, but just wanted to understand what you mean. Is that what @Jason clarified? That `delay` works fine!!

Answer (score 72):

I made it work with this:

```
.element {
   transition: height 3s ease-out, width 5s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for - shorthand for multiple properties. Thanks!

Comment: This is a straight-forward way to combine multiple transitions. But if there are more than 3 properties to transition it starts to get clunky. [@Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17117992/6908282) would be the right approach in that case. Although it need a little bit of initial understanding

Answer (score 5):

One important thing to note is that the CSS `transition` property itself is a shorthand - *as mentioned in the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)* :

> The `transition` CSS property is a shorthand property for `transition-property`, `transition-duration`, `transition-timing-function`, and `transition-delay`.

The ideal use of this shorthand is to combine the various [Constituent properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#constituent_properties) of a single transition. If this is used to combine multiple transitions, it will start to get clunky.

So when you have more than 2 transitions on the same element which different constituent properties, it becomes easier to write them individually instead of using the `transition` shorthand. For example:

This is the shorthand version(Option 1) of multiple transitions on one element:

```
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-out, filter 0.1s ease-out, color 0.25s ease-in 0.2s;
```

As you can see, this gets clunky and a little bit harder to visualize.
The same CSS can be applied like this(Option 2):

```
transition-property: transform, box-shadow, filter, color;
transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.2s, 0.2s, 0.25s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-out, ease-out, ease-in;
transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s, 0.2s
```

Of course, ultimately it all just comes down to your preference of typing and maintaining your source code. But I personally prefer the 2nd option.

---

### TIP:

Additional benefit of using this is, if one of the Constituent properties is same for all transitions, you don't need to mention it multiple times. For example, in the above example, if the `transition-duration` was the same(`0.5s`) for all, you write it like this:

```
transition-property: transform, box-shadow, filter, color;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-out, ease-out, ease-in;
transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s, 0.2s
```

Answer (score 2):

By having the .5s delay on transitioning the opacity property, the element will be completely transparent (and thus invisible) the whole time its height is transitioning. So the only thing you will actually see is the opacity changing. So you will get the same effect as leaving the height property out of the transition :

"transition: opacity .5s .5s;"

Is that what you're wanting? If not, and you're wanting to see the height transition, you can't have an opacity of zero during the whole time that it's transitioning.

Comment: This doesn't work either, as the height will stay 0 during the transition of the opacity.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me understand / streamline, only what I needed to animate:

```
// SCSS - Multiple Animation: Properties | durations | etc.
// on hover, animate div (width/opacity) - from: {0px, 0} to: {100vw, 1}

.base {
  max-width: 0vw;
  opacity: 0;

  transition-property: max-width, opacity; // relative order
  transition-duration: 2s, 4s; // effects relatively ordered animation properties
  transition-delay: 6s; // effects delay of all animation properties
  animation-timing-function: ease;

  &:hover {
    max-width: 100vw;
    opacity: 1;

    transition-duration: 5s; // effects duration of all aniomation properties
    transition-delay: 2s, 7s; // effects relatively ordered animation properties
  }
}
```

~ This applies for all transition properties (duration, transition-timing-function, etc.) within the '.base' class

Answer (score -6):

I think that this should work:

```
.element {
   -webkit-transition: all .3s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s;
   -o-transition: all .3s;
   transition: all .3s;
}
```

Comment: this is wrong since you're using `all`, all other properties will be affected, what he wanna change are just the height and the opacity, not everything