# JQuery Slide Toggle not working on this sticky footer when transition: all used?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm a little abashed as to why [this Sticky footer](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/5p4k1hmz/1/) won't allow a slide toggle animation?

Is there a particular reason why this won't work properly?

```
#PopupMessage{
    width:95%;
    height:30px;
        background: #999;
    color: #ececec;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px; 
    margin:2%;
    padding:1%;
    border-radius:10px;
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
              -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
                         box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    transition: all 0.8s;
    display:none;
}

#PopupMessage:hover{
    opacity:0;
}
```

The hover effect works, yet for some reason the 'slideToggle' won't work in this context?

I also have an issue (not sure if it is project specific, since it doesn't happen on the fiddle) is that my footer disappears after a few seconds (as if i've double clicked, or similar).

Any suggestions as to why this is occuring?

Comment: Check my answer to see the hover animation

Comment: @DavideScanu I don't think you quite got that one right there...

Comment: @jbulter483 Well, what do you want to do when the mouse goes over the popup message?

Comment: when i run your project, the button i'm using to test disappears, with no 'sticky footer' ever appearing.

Comment: Because I added an hover opacity... If click the button and put the mouse on the bottom of the page the popup message will appear... In fact I gave you two links:

1) http://jsfiddle.net/5p4k1hmz/6/ (without hover effect)
2) http://jsfiddle.net/5p4k1hmz/8/ (with hover effect)

Comment: I think you missed the point unfortunately. (please refer to comments below thecodeparapox's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change transition to :

```
transition: opacity 0.8s;
```

Because, `.slideToggle()` worked on `display` property and you `hover` css is working with `opacity`. So  , for `:hover` just apply transition on `opacity`. It will not put effect on `slideToggle()`.

Based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065896/jquery-slide-toggle-not-working-on-this-sticky-footer/27066002#comment42645540_27066002), where OP wants to use `all` for transition but not for `display`:

```
transition: all 0.8s, display: 0s;
```

Comment: If, say, there was more than just a mere opacity change, could you do all 0.8s <not>display / something similar?

Comment: @jbutler483 you have describe properties you want to apply transition. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670075/css-transition-shorthand-with-multiple-properties

Comment: I feared that. I was using all simply for that fact it was saving me a lot of time writing out the same definition for color/etc

Comment: @that last update doesn't seem to work unfortunately - the msgbox just 'disappears' completely on hover

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/5p4k1hmz/3/

Your `transition: all 0.8s;` is getting in the way.

Try using `transition: opacity 0.8s;` instead.

Comment: I suppose there's no way around having both a transitional hover effect AND jquery slidetoggle?

Comment: See my update. Using 'all' is messing with jQuery's height animation.

Comment: If, say, there was more than just a mere opacity change, could you do all 0.8s <not>display / something similar? i.e. set all transitions to .8seconds, all but not this display property

Answer (score 0):

You need to removed transition and it works, see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/5p4k1hmz/1/)

You can also define the time taken in the slide toggle, see the documentation for more info [Slide Toggle doc](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```js
     $('#openPopup').click(function () {
         $('#PopupMessage').slideToggle("slow", function () {
             // Animation complete.
         });
     });
```

```css
#PopupMessage {
    width:95%;
    height:30px;
    background: #999;
    color: #ececec;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    margin:2%;
    padding:1%;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    display:none;
}
#PopupMessage:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="openPopup">Press me to show popup</button>
<div id="PopupMessage">this will be popup message</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before to start:

toggle functions are deprecated in jQuery 2.1.0.

Anyway, the problem is that you have put in your CSS code:

```
transition: all 0.8s;
```

that makes a conflict with javascript animations. As you can see without this code, your script works perfectly:

http://jsfiddle.net/5p4k1hmz/5/

If you want more control of events you can use jQuery 1.7.2 and use the toggle function with slideUp() and slideDown() functions:

http://jsfiddle.net/5p4k1hmz/6/

If you want an hover effect with opacity: 0 here there is a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/5p4k1hmz/8/