# CSS transition is not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari

When you hover over image1div, it scales to 0.95 and fades to 80% opacity. It works in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. It fades and scales instantly in Safari rather than smoothly in 0.5s.

```
.image1div {
 width: 350px;
 height: 350px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 float: right;
 background-color: #5a89ad;
 background-size: cover;
 filter:alpha(opacity=100);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
     -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
         transform: scale(1,1);
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
         transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;    
}

.image1div:not(.no-hover):hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95,0.95);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.95,0.95);
          transform: scale(0.95,0.95);
  opacity:0.8;
  filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Comment: Which version of safari are you testing in? Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Version 8.0.3 (10600.3.18). I can try and make a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/60fnxv9r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with the filter property.
Transition is supported by safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions
Also the filter property, but you need to add a prefix: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters 
Let me know if it helps, if not, provide more details and we will find a workaround.

-- EDIT
Instead of transition: opacity, transform. Use all, or check out how you can add multiple properties [CSS transition shorthand with multiple properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670075/css-transition-shorthand-with-multiple-properties)

Comment: Do you mean add -webkit- before filter? http://jsfiddle.net/60fnxv9r/1/ does not seem to be working

Comment: The problem with all is that there's an unwanted property and I don't actually know what it is

Comment: Details: The background-image of the div changes on-click of another div, and the background-images are different sizes (not squares). So it ends up transitioning a "stretch" like movement between changes when I use all, and I don't want that.

Comment: Regarding your last issue, you need to wrap a fiddle for that. The initial question was answered, tested in safari and it works.

Comment: Yep, using all works, and I've decided that the effect it does is actually sort of cool, so I guess I can deal with it. Thanks!