# How to have multiple CSS color transitions on a single text line?

Tags: css

I'm trying to modify the text's color when hover with multiple color transitions but I can only change one color. Here is my CSS snippet.

```
#text       {font:9px 'Arial'; color:#000000; transition-duration: 3s;}
#text:hover {color:#FFFFFF;}
```

Not just `#000000` to `#FFFFFF`, but `#000000`→`#FF0000`→`#0000FF`→`#FFFFFF`

How to have multiple CSS color transitions on a single text line?

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen? I'm assuming that is what you've gotten to currently work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have multiple CSS transitions on an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048313/how-to-have-multiple-css-transitions-on-an-element) .. are you sure you aren't looking for an animation... a transition just changes something to -> from.

Comment: recheck my answer and demo updated for 3 seconds transition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) which allow you to use keyframes to define multiple state changes.

Your example would look like this:

```
#text:hover {
    animation: 3s multicolor;
}
@keyframes multicolor {
    0% {
        color: #000;
    }
    33% {
        color: #FF0000;
    }
    66% {
        color: #0000FF;
    }
    100% {
        color: #FFF;
    }
}
```

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd9Ka/1/)** that includes the -webkit prefix (omitted in the answer for brevity)

Comment: Thanks! But I've just got a problem. If I unhover it, it recovers instantly. How do I fix this?

Comment: @user2190490 this is not supported on many browsers but javascript it is

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out animation keyframes for CSS animations. You are able to specify the state of your text at whatever intervals you like (in this case, define your text color). W3 Schools has more info on the subject, take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp