# CSS3 Animation doesn't work

Tags: css, animation

I am using in my app the [IcoMoon App](http://icomoon.io/app/) fonts, for symbols.

At some part of my app, I like to use a rotating arrow by using the CSS3 Animation options, but for some reason, this doesn't work for me.

You can see my live code in **[FiddleJS](http://fiddle.jshell.net/merianos/6gvK4/)**

As you can see, in the element

```
<i class="loading icon-progress rotate"></i>
```

I have implement all the appropriate classes, but the animation does not run. Can somebody to help me ?

Am I doing something wrong ?

**NOTE:** I also have try the following in my CSS Code

```
.rotate
{
    ....
}
```

but still no results

The font I have installed is the following : http://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/9c89e0f9cb/BusinessDirectory/style.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at your fiddle and if you remove the top: 0px and left: 0px property in each animation step, the animation works.

This link explains why:
[Stackoverflow - Multiple properties in keyframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048313/how-to-have-multiple-css-transitions-on-an-element)

I've tried that with percentage, em and rem and it seems like positional properties are not wanted in your keyframes.

```
@keyframes rotationAnimation
{
  0%
  {
    transform : rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  100%
  {
    transform : rotate(360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotationAnimation
{
  0%
  {
    -moz-transform : rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  100%
  {
    -moz-transform : rotate(360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotationAnimation
{
  0%
  {
    -webkit-transform : rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  100%
  {
    -webkit-transform : rotate(360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotationAnimation
{
  0%
  {
    -o-transform : rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  100%
  {
    -o-transform : rotate(360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotationAnimation
{
  0%
  {
    -ms-transform : rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  100%
  {
    -ms-transform : rotate(360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
}
```

Above code works - funny thing if you use margin-* properties in one of the keyframes the margin gets animated not the rotate.
I've not enough CSS3 expertize to know why :/

edit:
Okay I've played a little more aaaand you need to write additional properties into the *-transform like

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotationAnimation
{
  0%
  {
    -webkit-transform : rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg), left:0,top: 0;
  }
  100%
  {
    -webkit-transform : rotate(360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg), left:0, top:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David. Your answer is correct. I will mark your answer as correct in a few minutes :) Thanks again !!!