# Setting the background image at a particular place on the web page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add some animation to the background image. I am trying to rise it upwards for a particular height, how can i do That?

```
.riseImages {
   position: absolute;      
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 4;
   background-image: url("img/page1/bg shapes.png");
   background-repeat: repeat;
   background-size: 350px;
   opacity: 0.3;
   border-left: 1px solid blueviolet;
   border-right: 1px solid blueviolet;
   background-size: 350px 300px;
 }

 .topRise {
           top: 0px;
           left: 0px;
         }

 .bottomRise {
           top: 500px;
           left: 0px;
      }
```

Comment: The most naive solution would be setting margin to negative values

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have multiple CSS transitions on an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048313/how-to-have-multiple-css-transitions-on-an-element)

Answer (score 2):

yes, use `background-position`
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

```
.riseImages 
 {
   background-position: value;
   position: absolute;      
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 4;
   background-image: url("img/page1/bg shapes.png");
   background-repeat: repeat;
   background-size: 350px;
   opacity: 0.3;
   border-left: 1px solid blueviolet;
   border-right: 1px solid blueviolet;
   background-size: 350px 300px;
 }

 .topRise {
           top: 0px;
           left: 0px;
         }

 .bottomRise {
       top: 500px;
       left: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: its not working even after adding  background position.

Comment: function topRise() {
        $(".topRise").animate({
            top: "-300px"
        }, 30000, topSet);
    };

    function botRise() {
        $(".bottomRise").animate({
            top: "0px"
        }, 30000, botSet);
    };

    function topSet() {
        $(".topRise").css({
            //"display": "none",
            "top": "0px"
        });
        topRise();
    };

    function botSet() {
        $(".bottomRise").css({
            //"display": "none",
            "top": "300px"
        });
        botRise();
    };

    botRise();
    topRise();

Comment: actually i want background image to start rising from a particular height towards top upto a particular height on the web page