# CSS Transitions for various style values

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm working on getting better with CSS animations and transitions. What I'm trying to do is make the transition from a square to a circle and vice versa smoother. I know that I need to use the `transition` method in CSS to control this.

2 questions:

1. Why is the `transition` method not working in the below code snippet?
2. How do I go about making different `transition` properties for each changing value? i.e. 1 transition timing for changing the border radius, 1 transition timing for moving the circle to where the square is, etc.

```css
.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
  }

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all 1s alternate;
  }
  
.circle:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  }
  
.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  transition: all 1s alternate;
  }
  
.square:hover {
  border-radius: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container-flex">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
  }

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  
.circle:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  }
  
.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  
.square:hover {
  border-radius: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container-flex">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, so simple! Thanks!

As to my 2nd question, how do you designate different transition values for different style changes?

Comment: @JeremyCorbello use multiple transitions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048313/how-to-have-multiple-css-transitions-on-an-element

Comment: Oh, so I just specify the element within transition. I thought that was just for @keyframes. That's awesome, thanks!